# What is the word for the opposite of “cheek puff”?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, antonyms

How to name the face expression pictured on the right photo?
[image]

Comment: "sucking your cheeks in".

Comment: The famous Zoolander magnum look. I heard tell it can stop a blade in mid air.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got tons of hits when I did a search on ***"suck in cheeks"*** and ***"suck in your cheeks"***.  That seems to be pretty standard.

The other term is "fish face" because the act of sucking in one's cheeks makes the lips protrude and look very fishy!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for an answer Kristina! I've made a 3d model recently and want to name the face controllers for it. I've got for example the following two-word names: 'jaw jutt', 'nostrils extend', 'nose bend', 'eye squint', 'cheek puff' etc. According to your answer, how should I name this one? 'Cheek suck'?

Comment: Yes, I'd go with "cheek suck" which would juxtapose nicely against "cheek puff"!

Comment: You're talking about ingressive mouth air instead of egressive, in the case of _puff_, so _**cheek pucker**_ is probably a better descriptive term.

Comment: My only concern about "cheek pucker", @JohnLawler, is that lip pucker is so much more common and  "pucker", alone, almost always conjures the image of puckering lips, not cheeks.

Comment: This could also be called a ["duck face"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_face), although the sucked in cheeks are not a requirement for making a duck face, just the pooked out lips are generally enough to qualify.

Comment: @delliottg, this is what I know as a duckface... https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kappit.com%2Fimg%2Fpics%2F201501_1531_gcbbb_sm.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kappit.com%2Ftag%2Fduck-face-jokes%2F&docid=hADuxbNA3mcG4M&tbnid=896rEJBEDM3FRM%3A&w=300&h=250&bih=855&biw=1454&ved=0ahUKEwjW25Sp4ubMAhWq7oMKHZGaCX0QMwh9KCEwIQ&iact=mrc&uact=8